# SAML 2.0 response verification

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

Integrating one of my application with with SAML 2.0 single sign on. Using Okta provider for this. I came to the point where I receive base64 encoded "SAML response token" after successful authetication in okta and redirected back to my application. Within this token I see all the user details I need but here comes my question. Do I need to verify that response any futher or shall I just trust what I receice? Considering this token also contains signarure?

My idea for security would be to reach Okta again and verify if this was really issued by Okta. Not sure if this is even possible.

Using NodeJS for verification.

Comment: This depends on whether you are on REDIRECT/POST binding where they return AuthnResponse via the browser or rather the ARTIFACT binding where it's your server that calls their artifact endpoint.

Comment: Is "Okta" here the SP?

Comment: Yes, Okta is the SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *SAML response token* you mean the `samlp:Response` issued according to the Web Browser Passsive SSO profile then then response contains an assertion and the assertion is **signed** by the Identity Provider (additionally, the whole response can also be signed).

There's a critical security requirement to always validate the response signature. This is mentioned in the [SAML specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf), section 4.1.4.3

The reason for this is as follows: in the Web Browser SSO Profile the token is returned by the Identity Provider in a web page that contains a simple form with `SAMLResponse` and `RelayState` fields and a bit of code that just autoPOSTs this form to your app. Technically, this means that for a short time the token is controlled by the user's web browser and this is where the token can be altered (or forged).

Thus, the protocol security heavily relies on the token's integrity which is achieved with the crypto signature - it's just a plain old XMLDSig signature applied to the SAML.

Your goal, as a token receiver is not only to validate the signature but also check the signature's certificate and compare it to the certificate you expect from the trusted provider (or a list of certificates of trusted providers).

Skipping this step makes your application vulnerable:

- skipping the verification means users can alter the token (add/create/delete) claims to the assertion, the signature verification would fail but you skip it
- skipping certificate matching against known certificate means users can forge their own assertions, sign it using a dummy certificate and present to your application. The signature verification step would succeed but you won't be aware that a dummy certificate was used to sign the assertion

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the proper token validation on a backend (don't blame you, it's a pain), then switch to OIDC. That's a better fit for authentication and authorization for the frontend.

If, however, the SAML response is sent to and handled by a backend, and some other token is being forwarded to your application, then you should evaluate what the requirement for the validation of that token is.

What isn't clear in your question is where in the user flow we're talking about, hence the number of comments on my answer.

Comment: I wish, but saml 2.0 is a must.

Comment: You can't safely validate SAML on the frontend. If you don't have a backend doing validation, it can't be trusted.

Comment: OIDC specification requires the Id Token to be validated. There's not too much difference. Most of the time the OIDC client (relying party) must call out to the OIDC provider ('server to server communication) to read the JWKS from the JWKS URI.

Comment: Many SAML Service Provider implementation library already doo the SAML response validation for you.

Comment: Yes, but you can't put that validation in frontend code (that is, code that will run on the client) because you cannot trust the frontend. This is what OAuth and OIDC was made for.

Comment: The SAML response actually arrives to backend and then it generates token for frontend authorization.

Comment: *your application is being sent a token by Okta then you should be okay.* No, you are not. The token is POSTed into your application and there's a risk of forging/tampering with the token. That's why SAML tokens are **signed**. The app's backend just has to validate the signature and validate that the signature's certificate is on the list of trusted certificates. I am downvoting your answer, sorry.

Comment: Did you read all of the comments? The one above you is op stating that the SAML response is being handled by a backend.

Comment: Yes, it is. SAML responses are always handled by the backend but get there through the browser. Are you sure you understand how SAML works under the hood?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, the OP, Smolda stated "The SAML response actually arrives to backend and then it generates token for frontend authorization." I may be reading more into that comment than I should be, but that suggests that Okta is generating some OTHER token from the SAML Response. I will adjust my response to take the uncertainty into account.

Comment: It's fine now after the edit. Assuming that the token is safe without the validation sounded pretty scary considering the OP specifically asked about saml flow. Changed my voting.